# Windows Media Center alternative

Tags: windows, media-player

I am looking at an alternative to windows media center for recording and watching TV. Setting up the TV tuner in media center was super easy, but all the other software I've tried was difficult to set up. My video is coming from an S-Video input, and I would want to have a guide.

Like in Windows Media Center, I would want to be able to change the channel with an IR remote control. I would want it to be free. If there are multiple steps or programs to install, could I have detailed instructions?

Edit: It is ok if it doesn't support an IR remote if that is difficult to find.

Comment: Am I not clear enough or asking too much? If there is a software offering something similar to what I ask, it would be great to know.

Comment: Hardly any HTPC builds are still handling IR remotes very well. You could try media portal..

Answer (score 2):

[Kodi Entertainment Center](http://kodi.tv/) (former XMBC) will suit "all" your needs - and among other systems - it works on Linux as well, thus for free.

A second option is [MythTV](https://www.mythtv.org/), but capabilities are limited.

Updated: Next could be [OpenElec](http://openelec.tv/), but this is just OS - implementing Kodi. Not sure if the support of whatever standard is better or not.

Update2: OpenElec was transformed into [LibreElec](https://libreelec.tv/) which will run on almost any hardware. It is still a standalone OS. A lot of plugins, but a lot of them outdated. At least Youtube plugin works.

Comment: Kodi doesn't have good CableCard support (for DRM'ed channels). The OP hasn't explicitly mentioned this as a goal, but this may be an issue if seeking to migrate off WMC.

Comment: @Bala - Kodi does not need any cable card support, as it is a Operating system who should support the hardware. You can run Kodi on Windows or other 5 OSes, and especially plenty versions of Linux. You should choose such OS, which supports your hardware well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already knew about Kodi and I just got it working today(well partialy). I cant really mark this as best answer because I asked for instructions to help me setup Kodi.

Comment: @Dee: In the case of an ethernet connected tuner like HD HomeRun, it is the player that should support CableCard. CableCard is not exposed as hardware to the OS, but instead is used for DRM.

Comment: Allright, got it.. Well you are probably right.